# How Can I Create method In Java With Same Type Parameter?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

My code looks like below:

```
enum EnumType {
 CATEGORY,
 GROUP,
 MAIN
}
```

Methods:

```
public void call(EnumType type){
   switch(type):
     case CATEGORY:
        return methodForCategory();
     case GROUP:
        return methodForGroup();
     ...
}
public void methodForCategory(){
   ... Operations according to EnumType.CATEGORY
}
public void methodForGroup(){
   ... Operations according to EnumType.GROUP
}
public void methodForMain(){
   ... Operations according to EnumType.MAIN
}
```

But I want to call it without switch/case like below;

```
public void call(EnumType type){
    methodForType(EnumType type);
}
```

Is it possible or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Common approaches are to have actual classes, and override the methods (if you want them structured see composite pattern). If you want to have the methods separate from the hiearchy, double dispatch (or visitor pattern)

Answer (score 5):

You can create the method implementation inside the enum as below:

```
public enum EnumType {

  CATEGORY {

    @Override
    public void processMethod() {
      // Do something here
    }

  },
GROUP {

    @Override
    public void processMethod() {
      // Do something here
    }

  },
MAIN {

    @Override
    public void processMethod() {
      // Do something here
    }

  };

public abstract void processMethod();
}
```

And update call method implementation as:

```
public void call(EnumType type){
   type.processMethod();
}
```

And switch code should not return anything as method return type is `void`.

Comment: this solution can be used for basic static operations (for processMethod implementation). But I think that it is not effective solution for external dynamic operations (call method from other classes). Because it will be complex for an enum class?

Comment: The you can use Strategy pattern for it. Where the above approach will give the object of Strategy class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EnumMap` as a registry of methods and using the `Enum` supplied you can return the correct implementation of the `Runnable`. I have used `Runnable` as a functional interface as it takes no inputs and produces no output.

In another class where you have the business logic, you can initialize the `map` and add the corresponding `Runnable` implementation:

```
class Strategy{

    private final EnumMap<EnumType, Runnable> map;

    public Strategy(){
        //Initialize values here
        map = new EnumMap<>(EnumType.class);
        map.put(EnumType.CATEGORY, () -> {
            System.out.println("CATEGORY");
        });
        map.put(EnumType.GROUP, () -> {
            System.out.println("GROUP");
        });
        map.put(EnumType.MAIN, () -> {
            System.out.println("MAIN");
        });
    }

    public void call(EnumType type){
        map.get(type).run();
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke the `call()` method by supplying the type of Enum as a parameter:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Strategy str = new Strategy();
    str.call(EnumType.CATEGORY);
    str.call(EnumType.GROUP);
    str.call(EnumType.MAIN);
}
```

Comment: Actually you could make the _value_ part of the `EnumMap` any [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), couldn't you?

Comment: @Abra That will depend on the use case, here OP needs a method which takes no input or return no output for that I have used a `Runnable`, if OP needed to return something without taking any input I would've gone for a `Supplier`