# avoiding if conditions for similar type of checks

Tags: java, java-8

Is there anyway to avoid these if conditions? because there may be different type of objects coming in.

```
if ("OpenOrder".equals(order.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
    return OpenOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((OpenOrder) order); //Returns String
}
if ("ExecutionOrder".equals(order.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
    return ExecutionOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((ExecutionOrder) order); //Returns String
}
```

Comment: Looking for `instanceof`?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a design pattern like [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: I think you can achieve this like https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933563/4762502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Router pattern to do this. Simple add the computations in a Map like this:

```
Map<String, Function> router = new HashMap<>();

router.put("OpenOrder", (value) -> OpenOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((OpenOrder) value));
router.put("ExecutionOrder", (value) -> ExecutionOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((ExecutionOrder) order));
```

And you can route the order using the String key. Here is a "OpenOrder" example:

```
String result = (String) router.get("OpenOrder").apply(order);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it. Which one to choose, depends on your needs and in this case in particular on how many different types of objects you will have.
I suggest looking at concepts like interfaces and inheritance and on specific design patterns.

One approach I tend to like, although still not perfect, works as follows:

```
interface Order {

}

interface OrderBuilder<T> {
    T forType();
    Object createOFSMessage(Order order);
}

class OpenOrderBuilder<OpenOrder> implements OrderBuilder {
    @Override
    OpenOrder forType() {
        return OpenOrder.class;
    }
    ...
}

class ExecutionOrderBuilder<ExecutionOrder> implements OrderBuilder {
    @Override
    ExecutionOrder forType() {
        return ExecutionOrder.class;
    }
    ...
}

class MyProcessor {
    Map<Class, OrderBuilder> obs;

    public void initialize() {
        List<OrderBuilder> builders = new ArrayList<>();
        builders.add(new OpenOrderBuilder());
        builders.add(new ExecutionOrderBuilder());

        obs = new HashMap<Class, OrderBuilder>();
        for(OrderBuilder b : builders) {
            obs.put(b.forType(), b);
        }
    }

    public Object createOFSMessage(Order order) {
        return obs.get(order.getClass()).createOFSMessage(order);
    }
}
```

In the above example, adding a new implementation would just consist of adding an entry to the `builders` collection. While in the example above it's done manually, normally this is done through `Dependency Injection` and frameworks like `spring` (in which case, the `initialize` method may turn into a constructor with `builders` as an `@Autowired` argument).

There are of course other ways, some more simple some more complicated. The best way really depends on what you have to do and one key rule: the less code you have the better.

Answer (score 0):

First one should not forget the switch-on-string:

```
switch (order.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
case "OpenOrder":
    return OpenOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((OpenOrder) order); //Returns String
case "ExecutionOrder":
    return ExecutionOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((ExecutionOrder) order); //Returns String
}
```

The code however shows inheritance being used in combination with static child class factories. Evidently a createOFSMessage is not desired in the Order base class.

Then use a non-static "builder" - a factory. Follow the [*strategy pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the type when calling the method, this code can help you :

```
    private String CreateOFSMessage(Class<T> classOrder) {

      if ("OpenOrder".equals(classOrder.getSimpleName())) {
            return OpenOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((classOrder) order); 
       }else if ("ExecutionOrder".equals(classOrder.getSimpleName())) {
            return ExecutionOrderBuilder.createOFSMessage((classOrder) order);            
       }
     }
```